# Text selection issue with embedded JavaFX into SWT

Tags: javafx, swt, textselection

I am having a problem with my JavaFX `TextArea`. I use the `FXCanvas` to embed an few JavaFX controls into an SWT composite. Everything works fine except for the `TextArea` which doesn't allow me to highlight text by dragging. Double click and "right click"/"select all" work fine, so text selection does work.

My objects are defined in an FXML file, you cannot do anything simpler:

```
<Accordion fx:id="accordion" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.kratos.birt.report.data.oda.kairosdb.ui.FXMLController">
  <panes>
    <TitledPane fx:id="builderPane" text="Query Builder">
      ...
    </TitledPane>
    <TitledPane fx:id="jsonPane" text="Raw Query">
      <content>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <Label text="Enter your query:">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea fx:id="queryArea" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
      </content>
    </TitledPane>
  </panes>
</Accordion>
```

I don't do any modification on it in the code, except for setting some text. The dragging selection doesn't work either if the `TextArea` isn't in the `Accordion` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to downgrade the version of the JRE (and thus the version of JavaFX) from 8 to 7.